# Android select options menu

Tags: java, android

I am using this code for making option menu in android:

```
    gender1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list1.add("Gender");
    list1.add("Male");
    list1.add("Female");

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
    dataAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    gender1.setAdapter(dataAdapter1);
```

And the xml:

```
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/input_register_bg"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:textColor="@color/input_login_hint"
        android:popupBackground="@color/input_login_hint"
        android:dropDownVerticalOffset="20dp"
        android:clickable="false" />
```

My problem is that it works on emulator and doesn't work on my phone. When I click on it, it never shows items but in emulator it works fine.

Comment: what doesn't work on your phone? spinner doesn't displays or it displays but doesn't show list? Please include all the information when posting question.

Comment: its display the spinner but when i click on it no thing shown but in emulator
its work

Comment: where your populating the spinner? in `onCreate` or in any other method?

Comment: yes the code is on  onCreate

Comment: then post your class, I cant tell where is the problem like this

Comment: i think there are some version of android dosent support this code its work on some device and other not